# Как можно в цикле получить все элементы последовательности?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Есть `XMLTYPE` со следующим содержимым:

```
userlist XMLType := XMLType(<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <users>
        <user>
            <name>user1</name>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>user2</name>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>user3</name>
        </user>
    </users>');
```

Как можно в PL/SQL блоке циклом получить все элементы `user`?

Можно найти много решений с `XMLTable`, но это SQL функция и для PL/SQL интерпретатора она не известна.

```
declare xtab XMLTable;
begin null;
end;
/
```

> PLS-00201: identifier 'XMLTABLE' must be declared

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle Pl/SQL: Loop through XMLTYPE nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/985894) от участника [@pistacchio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42636/pistacchio)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/985894

Answer (score 2):

Для простых задач можно воспользоваться функциями самого [XMLTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/XMLTYPE.html#GUID-2B092C51-6946-43A8-831F-887DABF9EA41):

```
declare
    ul XMLType := XMLType('<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <users>
        <user id="111">
            <name>user1</name>
        </user>
        <user id="222">
            <name>user2</name>
        </user>
        <user id="333">
            <name>user3</name>
        </user>
    </users>');
    counter int := 1;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line ('users:');
    while ul.existsNode ('//user['||counter||']') = 1 loop
        dbms_output.put_line (
            '   id='||ul.extract ('//user['||counter||']/@id').getNumberVal()||
            ' name='||ul.extract ('//user['||counter||']/name/text()').getStringVal());
        counter := counter+1;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Результат

```
users:
   id=111 name=user1
   id=222 name=user2
   id=333 name=user3
```

Answer (score 2):

Для больших XML документов со сложной структурой для повышения производительности рекомендуется воспользоваться программным интерфейсом [PL/SQL DOM API for XMLType](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/PLSQL-APIs-for-XMLType.html#GUID-629DC11A-283C-4A89-AB96-DE142E5FF34B).

В вопросе представлен простой документ, но только для примера:

```
declare
    xml XMLType := XMLType('<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <users>
        <user id="111">
            <name>user1</name>
        </user>
        <user id="222">
            <name>user2</name>
        </user>
        <user id="333">
            <name>user3</name>
        </user>
    </users>');
    dom dbms_xmldom.domdocument := dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument (xmldoc=>xml);
    userlist dbms_xmldom.domnodelist;
    usernode dbms_xmldom.domnode;
begin
    userlist := dbms_xmldom.getElementsByTagName (dom, 'user');
    dbms_output.put_line ('users:');
    for ui in 0..dbms_xmldom.getLength (userlist)-1 loop
        usernode := dbms_xmldom.item (userlist, ui);
        dbms_output.put_line ('   id=' ||
            dbms_xmldom.getAttribute (dbms_xmldom.makeElement(usernode), 'id')||
                              ' user='||
            dbms_xmldom.getNodeValue (dbms_xmldom.getFirstChild (
                                      dbms_xmldom.getFirstChild (usernode ))));
    end loop;
    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument (dom);
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
users:
   id=111 user=user1
   id=222 user=user2
   id=333 user=user3
```